# como soluciono este error en deploy con heroku

Tags: python, heroku

Este error es el que me sale al intentar hacer el deploy en heroku ,me podrian ayudar, es mi primer intento de hacer un deploy y me he encontrado con errores que no he podido comprender, si alguien tiene alguna ayuda sera bien recibida

```
Collecting psycopg2==2.8.6
     Downloading psycopg2-2.8.6.tar.gz (383 kB)
   Collecting py2exe==0.10.1.0
     Downloading py2exe-0.10.1.0.tar.gz (104 kB)
       ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
        command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-jzhxv2xo/py2exe/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-jzhxv2xo/py2exe/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-zqwmc0ba
            cwd: /tmp/pip-install-jzhxv2xo/py2exe/
       Complete output (17 lines):
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
         File "/tmp/pip-install-jzhxv2xo/py2exe/setup.py", line 16, in <module>
           from py2exe.py2exe_distutils import Dist, Interpreter, BuildInterpreters
         File "/tmp/pip-install-jzhxv2xo/py2exe/py2exe/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
           patch_distutils()
         File "/tmp/pip-install-jzhxv2xo/py2exe/py2exe/patch_distutils.py", line 68, in patch_distutils
           from . import distutils_buildexe
         File "/tmp/pip-install-jzhxv2xo/py2exe/py2exe/distutils_buildexe.py", line 91, in <module>
           from . import runtime
         File "/tmp/pip-install-jzhxv2xo/py2exe/py2exe/runtime.py", line 3, in <module>
           from .dllfinder import Scanner, pydll
         File "/tmp/pip-install-jzhxv2xo/py2exe/py2exe/dllfinder.py", line 5, in <module>
           from . import _wapi
         File "/tmp/pip-install-jzhxv2xo/py2exe/py2exe/_wapi.py", line 4, in <module>
           _kernel32 = WinDLL("kernel32")
       NameError: name 'WinDLL' is not defined
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
  Push failed
```

Comment: Creería que quitando py2exe. Py2exe sirve para crear ejecutables para Windows y tu deploy no lo estás haciendo en Windows por lo que no encuentra las librerías que espera encontrar y falla.

Comment: si estoy haciendo en deploy en windows, intentare quitando el py2exe, y despues comento como me fue